# convert foreach-loop to for-loop for Viewdata["terr"] which is list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, for-loop, foreach, viewdata

I have a list of checkbox like:

```
<% foreach (var tobj in (ViewData["terr"] as List<Location>))
{ %>
   <input type="checkbox" name="terr" id="<%: tobj.Location_Id %>" value="<%: tobj.Location_Id %>" disabled="disabled"/> 
   <span id="<%: tobj.Location_Name %>"> <%: tobj.Location_Name %> </span>
   <br />
<% } %>
```

But I want to display 3 or 4 checkbox in one row. and for that I need to conver foreach to for loop. I am not able to achieve this. Hope anyone can help me in this.

Comment: What is the problem you're running into when converting the foreach to a for loop?

Comment: in single iteration I want to display 3 or 4 index value. And I got that from answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why you cannot accomplish what you need in the foreach loop though. If you updated your question with a bit more info we could probably help you debug the initial foreach loop. Also if your using MVC 3 i recommend the Razor view engine, the syntax is a lot nicer.

The for loop equivalent:

```
<% { var locations = (List<Location>)ViewData["terr"] } %>

<% for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count(); i++)
{ %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="terr" id="<%: locations[i].Location_Id %>" value="<%: locations[i].Location_Id %>" disabled="disabled"/> 
    <span id="<%: locations[i].Location_Name %>"> <%: locations[i].Location_Name %> </span>
    <br />
<% } %>
```

Comment: thankx for answer and suggestion. For this project I have to use aspx.  and its giving error `CS0103: The name 'locations' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: solved the error.. I just needed to close the } braces of first `{` after for loop.

Comment: Great. Solved your issue then?